# (13)Permission denied: access to /~me denied

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I am trying to configure Apache httpd.conf (on my CentOS 6.4) to allow access to my user directory (i.e. ~me/public_html/index.html).

I changed **the original** `httpd.conf` (i.e. out-of-the-box) as follows:

```
[root@myhost www]# diff /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.orig.out-of-the-box 
366c366
<     #UserDir disabled
---
>     UserDir disabled
373c373
<     UserDir public_html
---
>     #UserDir public_html
```

This should in principle provide access to `http://myhost/~me` but instead, I am getting the dreaded error:

```
You don't have permission to access /~me on this server.
```

I checked the file /var/log/httpd/error_log and, sure enough, it reads:

```
(13)Permission denied: access to /~me denied
```

The first weird thing I noticed is that a `/` is prepended to `~me`.

- Where does that leading `/` come  from?
- Is it only a "red herring"?
- Or is this pointing to the root cause of the problem (i.e. something else I need to modify in httpd.conf)?

Most importantly, since I know that my  `~me/public_html` is has world-readable permissions, **how do I troubleshoot a problem like this?**

Is there a way to find out **why** "access to /~me denied"?

- SELinux?
- httpd.conf?
- directory permissions?
- all of the above?

---

**Update 1**, answering the 2 questions in the comments by @UlrichSchwarz  below:

1. The home directory does seem to have the 'x' permission:

   [root@myhost ~]# ls -lad /home/me

   drwxr-xr-x. 33 me me 4096 Feb  8 16:30 /home/me
2. SELinux info on public_html:

   [root@myhost ~]# ls -Z -d /home/me/public_html/

   drwxrwxr-x. me me unconfined_u:object_r:file_t:s0  /home/me/public_html/

---

**Update 2**, after I verified that this is indeed an SELinux issue (thanks to the tip by @Scolytus):

1. I ran the command:

   chcon -R -t httpd_user_content_t /home/me/public_html/

   Still no go.

   [root@myhost ~]# ls -Z -d /home/me/public_html/

   drwxrwxr-x. me me unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 /home/me/public_html/
2. Then I ran "Allow HTTPD to read home directories" [from the command line](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-250779.html):

   setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs=1

   Still no go.

/var/log/httpd/error_log now shows (in addition to the (13)permission denied error) the following:

```
 [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
 [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
 [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
 [notice] Digest: done
 [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Perhaps the problem lies in the discrepancy between context_system_u and httpd_user_content_t?

What else do I need to do? (without disabling SELinux completely, that is)

---

**Update 3**, thanks to information in @lserni's answer, I discovered the [ausearch](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/Where_to_find_SELinux_permission_denial_details#ausearch) command:

```
ausearch -m avc --start today
```

Which provided the following output:

```
time->Fri Jul  4 09:16:44 2014
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1404479804.256:1312): arch=40000003 syscall=196 success=no exit=-13 a0=12c2c80 a1=bfeb1d00 a2=a34ff4 a3=2008171 items=0 ppid=5880 pid=5886 auid=0 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=193 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1404479804.256:1312): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=5886 comm="httpd" path="/home/me" dev=dm-3 ino=2 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:file_t:s0 tclass=dir
```

Huh? Why `/home/me` and not `/home/me/public_html`?

Here is the output of `ls -Zd /home/me/`:

```
drwxr-xr-x. me me system_u:object_r:file_t:s0      /home/me/
```

Should I run the `chcon -t httpd_user_content_t` on */home/me*, too?

Continuing to research...

---

**Update 4**: Success!

I ran the command:

```
chcon -t httpd_user_content_t /home/me/
```

And all is well now.

```
[root@myhost sa]# ls -Z -d /home/me/

drwxr-xr-x. me me system_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 /home/me/
```

Comment: The server will probably need `+x` on your home directory to see if you have a `public_html` present in the first place, is that the case?

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -Z -d public_html/`? (`-Z` lists SELinux info; this taken from [the SELinux FAQ](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/SELinux_FAQ/index.html#faq-entry-public_html))

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Thank you very much. I just posted answers to your questions. Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: The FAQ he linked tells you how you need to tag your public_html dir w/ SELinux enforcing.

Comment: You could try to disable SELinux temporarily, just to see whether it's actually the problem.

Comment: @Scolytus Bingo! I used [echo 0 > /selinux/enforce](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-centos-linux-temporarily-switchoff-selinux/) to temporarily disable SELinux and lo-and-behold, access to the `http://myhost/~me` is back again. I now have to consult the FAQ to tag my public_html w/ SELinux enforcing.

Comment: You might want to check/install the `sealert`/`setroubleshootd` combo. It can be a lifesaver. On my OpenSuSE system I can find some SE issues in the /var/log "auditd" log file; what distro are you using?

Comment: @lserni I am using `CentOS 6.4`. SELinux's audit log files seem to be in `/var/log/sa/` and the tool to decipher them seems to be `seaudit-report`.

Comment: *Of course*. Silly me: to be able to access `/home/me/public_html`, Apache needs to have the right to *read the /home/me directory content* (i.e. the names of the files and directories in there - the directory execute bit). See http://askubuntu.com/questions/26848/permissions-issue-how-can-apache-access-files-in-my-home-directory

Comment: @lserni Success! Thank you very much! (see my **Update 4** in the OP).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen [a slightly different version](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/Where_to_find_SELinux_permission_denial_details#ausearch) of the command you gave, supplied by `sealert`:

> SELinux denied access to /var/www/html/file1 requested by httpd.
>   /var/www/html/file1 has a context used for sharing by different
>   program. If you would like to share /var/www/html/file1 from httpd
>   also, **you need to change its file context to `public_content_t`**. If
>   you did not intend to this access, this could signal a intrusion
>   attempt.
>
> Allowing Access:
>
> You can alter the file context by executing chcon -t public_content_t
>   '/var/www/html/file1'

Fix Command:

```
chcon -t public_content_t '/var/www/html/file1'
```

> **how do I troubleshoot a problem like this?**

Most SELinux-related information is generally in the auditd logs, but you probably want some tool such as `sealert` to decode it for you. I've done a brief search and came up with this tool that I didn't know of, but seems interesting: [SELinux GUI](http://pandeyarpit.wordpress.com/selinux-an-introduction/selinux-gui-overview/).

**Addendum**: [Some examples with `semanage`](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/practical-selinux-for-the-beginner-contexts-and-labels/)

Comment: @lsemi +1 for the attempt to solve the mystery. I ran your `chcon -t public_content_t` command but it didn't help either. I suspect that the problem has to do with what the log says about *"httpd running as context system_u"*

Comment: Just to be sure, run a `ls -lZ` on the default httpd DocumentRoot - the one that Apache *is* able to read. Afterwards you can use `semanage`/`restorecon` to assign the same context to the public_html directory. Also see: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/practical-selinux-for-the-beginner-contexts-and-labels/

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/html/`

Comment: The hell. Then `semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t '/home/~me/public_html(/.*)?' && restorecon -Rv ''/home/~me/public_html'` *has* to work. I don't have a CentOS 64 available for testing, but I might perhaps give it a try on a VM this Sunday (can't promise anything yet, sorry).

Comment: The above is not exactly true. It is necessary, *but not sufficient*. See the comment on the question too. The whole path must be searchable by Apache.

Answer (score 2):

I can't check immediately, but I recall that commenting out the `UserDir disabled` isn't the same as enabling!

More specifically, I think you need to include a line in your https.conf file

```
Userdir enabled me
```

Comment: Everything is fine with the added line `UserDir public_html`. I guess you don't understand the `diff` output.

Comment: Besides, @Nick's answer came *after* I posted my findings about the problem being an **SELinux** issue **only**.

Comment: For the record, the SELinus stuff wasn't there when I posted my offer. Given the childish petulance of your comment, I suspect I was using diff (from about 1981) before you were born. If you had given a fulsome description of the problem in the first instance (i.e. admitting to using SELinux rather than just talking about permissions), I wouldn't have posted.